# Unable to construct api.Node object for kubelet: failed to get external ID from cloud provider: Failed to find object

Tags: kubernetes

Trying to use Cinder volumens on OpenStack as persistent volumes for my pods. As soon as I configure the cloudprovider and restart the kubelet, the kubelet fails to get its external ID from the cloud provider.

The OpenStack API is reachable via https using a comodo certificate. the comodo-ca-bundle is installed as trusted ca on the node. Using curl against the API works without --insecure and --cacert options.

Using kubernetes 1.1.0-alpha on centos 7

$ sudo journalctl -u kubelet

```
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.303887    4196 debugging.go:129]     Content-Length: 1159
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.303895    4196 debugging.go:129]     Content-Type: application/json
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.303950    4196 request.go:755] Response Body: {"kind":"NodeList","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"selfLink":"/api/v1/nodes","resourceVersion":"172921"},"items":[{"metadata":{"name":"192.168.100.80","selfLink":"/api/v1/nodes/192.168.100.80","uid":"b48b4cb9-676f-11e5-8521-fa163ef34ff1","resourceVersion":"172900","creationTimestamp":"2015-09-30T12:35:17Z","labels":{"kubernetes.io/hostname":"192.168.100.80"}},"spec":{"externalID":"192.168.100.80"},"status":{"capacity":{"cpu":"2","memory":"4047500Ki","pods":"40"},"conditions":[{"type":"Ready","status":"Unknown","lastHeartbeatTime":"2015-10-01T07:31:55Z","lastTransitionTime":"2015-10-01T07:32:36Z","reason":"Kubelet stopped posting node status."}],"addresses":[{"type":"LegacyHostIP","address":"192.168.100.80"},{"type":"InternalIP","address":"192.168.100.80"}],"nodeInfo":{"machineID":"dae72fe0cc064eb0b7797f25bfaf69df","systemUUID":"384A8E40-1296-9A42-AD77-445D83BB5888","bootID":"5c7eb3ff-d86f-41f2-b3eb-a39adf313a4f","kernelVersion":"3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64","osImage":"CentOS Linux 7 (Core)","containerRuntimeVersion":"docker://1.7.1","kubeletVersion":"v1.1.0-alpha.1.390+196f58b9cb25a2","kubeProxyVersion":"v1.1.0-alpha.1.390+196f58b9cb25a2"}}}]}
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.475016    4196 request.go:457] Request Body: {"kind":"DeleteOptions","apiVersion":"v1","gracePeriodSeconds":0}
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.475148    4196 debugging.go:101] curl -k -v -XDELETE  -H "Authorization: Bearer rhARkbozkWcrJyvdLQqF9TNO86KHjOsq" -H "User-Agent: kubelet/v1.1.0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/196f58b" https://localhost:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/fluentd-elasticsearch-192.168.100.80
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.526794    4196 debugging.go:120] DELETE https://localhost:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/fluentd-elasticsearch-192.168.100.80 200 OK in 51 milliseconds
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.526865    4196 debugging.go:126] Response Headers:
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.526897    4196 debugging.go:129]     Content-Type: application/json
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.526927    4196 debugging.go:129]     Date: Thu, 01 Oct 2015 07:40:26 GMT
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.526957    4196 debugging.go:129]     Content-Length: 1977
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.527056    4196 request.go:755] Response Body: {"kind":"Pod","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"name":"fluentd-elasticsearch-192.168.100.80","namespace":"kube-system","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/fluentd-elasticsearch-192.168.100.80","uid":"a90941f6-680f-11e5-988c-fa163e94cde4","resourceVersion":"172926","creationTimestamp":"2015-10-01T07:40:17Z","deletionTimestamp":"2015-10-01T07:40:26Z","deletionGracePeriodSeconds":0,"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/config.mirror":"mirror","kubernetes.io/config.seen":"2015-10-01T07:39:43.986114806Z","kubernetes.io/config.source":"file"}},"spec":{"volumes":[{"name":"varlog","hostPath":{"path":"/var/log"}},{"name":"varlibdockercontainers","hostPath":{"path":"/var/lib/docker/containers"}}],"containers":[{"name":"fluentd-elasticsearch","image":"gcr.io/google_containers/fluentd-elasticsearch:1.11","args":["-q"],"resources":{"limits":{"cpu":"100m"},"requests":{"cpu":"100m"}},"volumeMounts":[{"name":"varlog","mountPath":"/var/log"},{"name":"varlibdockercontainers","readOnly":true,"mountPath":"/var/lib/docker/containers"}],"terminationMessagePath":"/dev/termination-log","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent"}],"restartPolicy":"Always","terminationGracePeriodSeconds":30,"dnsPolicy":"ClusterFirst","nodeName":"192.168.100.80"},"status":{"phase":"Running","conditions":[{"type":"Ready","status":"True"}],"hostIP":"192.168.100.80","podIP":"172.16.58.24","startTime":"2015-10-01T07:40:17Z","containerStatuses":[{"name":"fluentd-elasticsearch","state":{"running":{"startedAt":"2015-10-01T07:37:23Z"}},"lastState":{"terminated":{"exitCode":137,"startedAt":"2015-10-01T07:23:00Z","finishedAt":"2015-10-01T07:33:17Z","containerID":"docker://1398736fd9b274132721206ccaf89030af5e8e304118d29286aec6b2529395ee"}},"ready":true,"restartCount":1,"image":"gcr.io/google_containers/fluentd-elasticsearch:1.11","imageID":"docker://03ba3d224c2a80600a0b44a9894ac0de5526d36b810b13924e33ada76f1e7406","containerID":"docker://d9ac24c8a0fbceea7c494bce73d56d6ea5f003f1d1b7b8ad3975fc7e3c7679b4"}]}}
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.528210    4196 status_manager.go:209] Pod "fluentd-elasticsearch-192.168.100.80" fully terminated and removed from etcd
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.675178    4196 debugging.go:101] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "User-Agent: kubelet/v1.1.0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/196f58b" -H "Authorization: Bearer rhARkbozkWcrJyvdLQqF9TNO86KHjOsq" https://localhost:6443/api/v1/services
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.710214    4196 debugging.go:120] GET https://localhost:6443/api/v1/services 200 OK in 34 milliseconds
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.710249    4196 debugging.go:126] Response Headers:
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.710260    4196 debugging.go:129]     Content-Type: application/json
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.710270    4196 debugging.go:129]     Date: Thu, 01 Oct 2015 07:40:26 GMT
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.710436    4196 request.go:755] Response Body: {"kind":"ServiceList","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"selfLink":"/api/v1/services","resourceVersion":"172927"},"items":[{"metadata":{"name":"kubernetes","namespace":"default","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/kubernetes","uid":"28717019-676b-11e5-afb9-fa163e94cde4","resourceVersion":"18","creationTimestamp":"2015-09-30T12:02:44Z","labels":{"component":"apiserver","provider":"kubernetes"}},"spec":{"ports":[{"protocol":"TCP","port":443,"targetPort":443}],"clusterIP":"10.100.0.1","type":"ClusterIP","sessionAffinity":"None"},"status":{"loadBalancer":{}}},{"metadata":{"name":"elasticsearch-logging","namespace":"kube-system","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/elasticsearch-logging","uid":"833c8df5-676b-11e5-958e-fa163e94cde4","resourceVersion":"153","creationTimestamp":"2015-09-30T12:05:16Z","labels":{"k8s-app":"elasticsearch-logging","kubernetes.io/cluster-service":"true","kubernetes.io/name":"Elasticsearch"}},"spec":{"ports":[{"protocol":"TCP","port":9200,"targetPort":"db"}],"selector":{"k8s-app":"elasticsearch-logging"},"clusterIP":"10.100.3.159","type":"ClusterIP","sessionAffinity":"None"},"status":{"loadBalancer":{}}},{"metadata":{"name":"kibana-logging","namespace":"kube-system","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kibana-logging","uid":"833043fa-676b-11e5-958e-fa163e94cde4","resourceVersion":"149","creationTimestamp":"2015-09-30T12:05:16Z","labels":{"k8s-app":"kibana-logging","kubernetes.io/cluster-service":"true","kubernetes.io/name":"Kibana"}},"spec":{"ports":[{"protocol":"TCP","port":5601,"targetPort":"ui"}],"selector":{"k8s-app":"kibana-logging"},"clusterIP":"10.100.136.111","type":"ClusterIP","sessionAffinity":"None"},"status":{"loadBalancer":{}}},{"metadata":{"name":"kube-dns","namespace":"kube-system","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns","uid":"8319ba13-676b-11e5-958e-fa163e94cde4","resourceVersion":"146","creationTimestamp":"2015-09-30T12:05:16Z","labels":{"k8s-app":"kube-dns
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: ","kubernetes.io/cluster-service":"true","kubernetes.io/name":"KubeDNS"}},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"dns","protocol":"UDP","port":53,"targetPort":53},{"name":"dns-tcp","protocol":"TCP","port":53,"targetPort":53}],"selector":{"k8s-app":"kube-dns"},"clusterIP":"10.100.0.10","type":"ClusterIP","sessionAffinity":"None"},"status":{"loadBalancer":{}}},{"metadata":{"name":"kube-ui","namespace":"kube-system","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-ui","uid":"83473271-676b-11e5-958e-fa163e94cde4","resourceVersion":"155","creationTimestamp":"2015-09-30T12:05:16Z","labels":{"k8s-app":"kube-ui","kubernetes.io/cluster-service":"true","kubernetes.io/name":"KubeUI"}},"spec":{"ports":[{"protocol":"TCP","port":80,"targetPort":8080}],"selector":{"k8s-app":"kube-ui"},"clusterIP":"10.100.246.61","type":"ClusterIP","sessionAffinity":"None"},"status":{"loadBalancer":{}}},{"metadata":{"name":"monitoring-grafana","namespace":"kube-system","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana","uid":"835da09c-676b-11e5-958e-fa163e94cde4","resourceVersion":"157","creationTimestamp":"2015-09-30T12:05:16Z","labels":{"kubernetes.io/cluster-service":"true","kubernetes.io/name":"Grafana"}},"spec":{"ports":[{"protocol":"TCP","port":80,"targetPort":8080}],"selector":{"k8s-app":"influxGrafana"},"clusterIP":"10.100.207.92","type":"ClusterIP","sessionAffinity":"None"},"status":{"loadBalancer":{}}},{"metadata":{"name":"monitoring-heapster","namespace":"kube-system","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-heapster","uid":"83367b90-676b-11e5-958e-fa163e94cde4","resourceVersion":"151","creationTimestamp":"2015-09-30T12:05:16Z","labels":{"kubernetes.io/cluster-service":"true","kubernetes.io/name":"Heapster"}},"spec":{"ports":[{"protocol":"TCP","port":80,"targetPort":8082}],"selector":{"k8s-app":"heapster"},"clusterIP":"10.100.119.4","type":"ClusterIP","sessionAffinity":"None"},"status":{"loadBalancer":{}}},{"metadata":{"name":"monitoring-influxdb","namespace":"kube-system","selfLink":"/api/v1/names
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: paces/kube-system/services/monitoring-influxdb","uid":"836c95b8-676b-11e5-958e-fa163e94cde4","resourceVersion":"159","creationTimestamp":"2015-09-30T12:05:16Z","labels":{"kubernetes.io/cluster-service":"true","kubernetes.io/name":"InfluxDB"}},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"http","protocol":"TCP","port":8083,"targetPort":8083},{"name":"api","protocol":"TCP","port":8086,"targetPort":8086}],"selector":{"k8s-app":"influxGrafana"},"clusterIP":"10.100.101.182","type":"ClusterIP","sessionAffinity":"None"},"status":{"loadBalancer":{}}},{"metadata":{"name":"reverseproxy","namespace":"kube-system","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/reverseproxy","uid":"15e65b7d-6776-11e5-a5d0-fa163e94cde4","resourceVersion":"10994","creationTimestamp":"2015-09-30T13:20:57Z","labels":{"k8s-app":"reverseproxy","kubernetes.io/cluster-service":"true","kubernetes.io/name":"reverseproxy"}},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"http","protocol":"TCP","port":8181,"targetPort":8181,"nodePort":80},{"name":"https","protocol":"TCP","port":8181,"targetPort":8181,"nodePort":443}],"selector":{"k8s-app":"reverseproxy"},"clusterIP":"10.100.168.84","type":"NodePort","sessionAffinity":"None"},"status":{"loadBalancer":{}}}]}
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.875150    4196 debugging.go:101] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "User-Agent: kubelet/v1.1.0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/196f58b" -H "Authorization: Bearer rhARkbozkWcrJyvdLQqF9TNO86KHjOsq" https://localhost:6443/api/v1/watch/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3D192.168.100.80&resourceVersion=172921
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.900981    4196 debugging.go:120] GET https://localhost:6443/api/v1/watch/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3D192.168.100.80&resourceVersion=172921 200 OK in 25 milliseconds
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.901009    4196 debugging.go:126] Response Headers:
Oct 01 07:40:26 [4196]: I1001 07:40:26.901018    4196 debugging.go:129]     Date: Thu, 01 Oct 2015 07:40:26 GMT
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.001744    4196 iowatcher.go:102] Unexpected EOF during watch stream event decoding: unexpected EOF
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.002685    4196 reflector.go:294] pkg/client/unversioned/cache/reflector.go:87: Unexpected watch close - watch lasted less than a second and no items received
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: W1001 07:40:27.002716    4196 reflector.go:224] pkg/client/unversioned/cache/reflector.go:87: watch of *api.Node ended with: very short watch
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.075065    4196 debugging.go:101] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "User-Agent: kubelet/v1.1.0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/196f58b" -H "Authorization: Bearer rhARkbozkWcrJyvdLQqF9TNO86KHjOsq" https://localhost:6443/api/v1/watch/services?resourceVersion=172927
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.101642    4196 debugging.go:120] GET https://localhost:6443/api/v1/watch/services?resourceVersion=172927 200 OK in 26 milliseconds
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.101689    4196 debugging.go:126] Response Headers:
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.101705    4196 debugging.go:129]     Date: Thu, 01 Oct 2015 07:40:27 GMT
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.104168    4196 openstack.go:164] openstack.Instances() called
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.133478    4196 openstack.go:201] Found 8 compute flavors
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.133519    4196 openstack.go:202] Claiming to support Instances
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: E1001 07:40:27.158908    4196 kubelet.go:846] Unable to construct api.Node object for kubelet: failed to get external ID from cloud provider: Failed to find object
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.202978    4196 iowatcher.go:102] Unexpected EOF during watch stream event decoding: unexpected EOF
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.203110    4196 reflector.go:294] pkg/client/unversioned/cache/reflector.go:87: Unexpected watch close - watch lasted less than a second and no items received
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: W1001 07:40:27.203136    4196 reflector.go:224] pkg/client/unversioned/cache/reflector.go:87: watch of *api.Service ended with: very short watch
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.275208    4196 debugging.go:101] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Authorization: Bearer rhARkbozkWcrJyvdLQqF9TNO86KHjOsq" -H "User-Agent: kubelet/v1.1.0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/196f58b" https://localhost:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3D192.168.100.80
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.308434    4196 debugging.go:120] GET https://localhost:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3D192.168.100.80 200 OK in 33 milliseconds
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.308464    4196 debugging.go:126] Response Headers:
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.308475    4196 debugging.go:129]     Content-Type: application/json
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.308484    4196 debugging.go:129]     Date: Thu, 01 Oct 2015 07:40:27 GMT
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.308491    4196 debugging.go:129]     Content-Length: 113
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.308524    4196 request.go:755] Response Body: {"kind":"PodList","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"selfLink":"/api/v1/pods","resourceVersion":"172941"},"items":[]}
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.308719    4196 config.go:252] Setting pods for source api
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.308753    4196 kubelet.go:1921] SyncLoop (REMOVE): "fluentd-elasticsearch-192.168.100.80_kube-system"
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.308931    4196 volumes.go:100] Used volume plugin "kubernetes.io/host-path" for varlog
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.308960    4196 volumes.go:100] Used volume plugin "kubernetes.io/host-path" for varlibdockercontainers
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.308977    4196 kubelet.go:2531] Generating status for "fluentd-elasticsearch-192.168.100.80_kube-system"
```

$ kubectl version

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1+",
GitVersion:"v1.1.0-alpha.1.390+196f58b9cb25a2", 
GitCommit:"196f58b9cb25a2222c7f9aacd624737910b03acb",
GitTreeState:"clean"}

Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1+",
GitVersion:"v1.1.0-alpha.1.390+196f58b9cb25a2",
GitCommit:
"196f58b9cb25a2222c7f9aacd624737910b03acb",
GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

$ cat /etc/os-release

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

$ cat /etc/kubernetes/kubelet

```
###
# kubernetes kubelet (node) config

# The address for the info server to serve on (set to 0.0.0.0 or "" for all interfaces)
KUBELET_ADDRESS="--address=0.0.0.0"

# The port for the info server to serve on
# KUBELET_PORT="--port=10250"

# You may leave this blank to use the actual hostname
KUBELET_HOSTNAME="--hostname_override=192.168.100.80"

# location of the api-server
KUBELET_API_SERVER="--api_servers=https://localhost:6443"

# Add your own!
KUBELET_ARGS="--cluster_dns=10.100.0.10 --cluster_domain=cluster.local --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.kubeconfig --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --v=9 --cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/cloud_config  --cloud-provider=openstack --machine-id-file=/etc/machine-id"
```

$ cat /etc/kubernetes/cloud_config

```
[Global]
auth-url=https://api.*******.de:5000/v2.0
username=username
password=password
region=RegionOne
tenant-id=4ee7b21351d94f2b96d363efe131b833
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kubelet is able to reach Openstack, however it is failing to find this node in the list of servers, in this tenant, and in this region.
`Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: I1001 07:40:27.133478    4196 openstack.go:201] Found 8 compute flavors
Oct 01 07:40:27 [4196]: E1001 07:40:27.158908    4196 kubelet.go:846] Unable to construct api.Node object for kubelet: failed to get external ID from cloud provider: Failed to find object`

Node's hostname is used to identify it from the list of servers provided by cloud provider. However, it can be overridden using --hostname_overide flag.

In your config, I see that you have overridden it with an ip, if this does not match the name of the server as reported by Nova, you are likely to get this error.

Comment: Thank you for this advise. I tried the private ip (which  is used without me setting it as the hostname), kube1, kube1.novalocal and the instance-id as hostname. Still had the same error.

Comment: Could you please post what nova show <instance id> says, based on that we can validate what needs to be in the --hostname_override. Another way  is to make sure that the vm's name is set to the result of `hostname` on the node and not use override flag at all.

Comment: The vm's name equaled the hostname. `--hostname-override=${hostname}` worked, but only after an update to `v1.1.0-alpha.1-653-g86b4e77`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: what if my kubernetes nodes are not provided by this provider? They won't be registered with the openstack API. In my case I'm trying to use block storage with Cinder from the cloud provider, but my cluster is bare metal. Is that even possible?

Comment: @MrE what you are trying to do is not possible as of now, but I know some one was trying to do cinder with bare metals, you can hit up the slack channel to see where its at.