# How do I get an invite to the Kubernetes Slack channel?

Tags: kubernetes

I've been trying to get help on [a Kubernetes question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36322006/kubernetes-using-openstack-cinder-from-one-cloud-provider-while-nodes-on-anothe) and I don't get answers, and one suggestion was to ask on the Kubernetes slack channel, however it seems to be on invite only or for google, intel, coreos and redhat email addresses.

So, how am I supposed to get an invite to the channel? 
The 'get my invite' options claims they sent me the invite, yet I didn't receive it and there is no option to resend it.

This question is a real question, and it also meant to attrack attention to the Kubernetes team to answer the related question. Since Kubernetes uses Stack Overflow as their support Q&A system and redirect the Github question to SO, I believe it is fair to try to get their attention here.

Comment: I would recommend you to ask this on Quora which is more friendly to this kind of questions. Here you're most likely to get off-topic.

Comment: http://slack.kubernetes.io/, "get my invite", no?

Comment: well, I did that at some point but never got an email. I checked spam etc. Now when I try again it says check for that email, but I don't have it and there are no options to resend it. So I guess it may be a slack problem.

Comment: You can also try to ping them via https://twitter.com/kubernetesio. Just ask this in your tweet and mention their @kubernetesio.

Answer (score 27):

http://slack.kubernetes.io is indeed the way to get yourself invited.

It sounds like there were some issue this morning (perhaps with Slack?), but the invites seem to be working now.  See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23823.  It's possible you're seeing the same issue (or that you are the same person :) ).  Let me know if there is still a problem.

Comment: No https   on slack.kubernetes.io :( ?

Comment: http://slack.k8s.io/ appears to be another URL to the same signup page, in case anyone else noticed this and was wondering.